# Intel graphics kernel mode driver is causing Windows to resume slowly

Tags: windows

My installation of Windows Vista says that the Intel graphics kernel mode driver is causing Windows to resume slowly and offers an option to remove it from the list.
I presume this would increase my speed. Should I do it? If necessary, can I restore the driver?

Answer (score 0):

As the display driver is required for graphics acceleration, you should not remove it.  You may experience things like an inability to change resolution to anything higher than 640x480, Aero not working any more, and/or graphically intensive applications failing to start or not working properly.

Try updating the driver to a later version from the Intel system tray applet or Control Panel applet.